# what is difference between as far as I'm aware and as far as I'm concerned

Tags: difference

I am curious to know what different between as far as I am aware and as far as I am concerned is?

those are the same meaning?

Comment: Have you looked up 'aware' and 'concerned' in a dictionary?

Comment: You can be *aware* of something without being concerned about it. In fact, you can be *aware* of something and not care about it in the slightest.